# Optimized Layout for Kinesis Advantage

Tags: keyboard

One of the most powerful features of the Kinesis dvantage keyboards is the ability to remap keys.  I've been using one for about 6 months with the Colemak layout and am loving it.  Below is my layout.  I primarily use Matlab.  What is your optimal layout?

[image]

The 2 things I found most useful were to put the shift key under the left thumb and putting all the arrows under the right hand.  This allows me to comfortably hit ctrl+shift with my thumb and move with the arrows on the other hand to select text and navigate around excel.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

My version of Kinesis Advantage layout:

[image]

For mac you can create custom layout (see [TN2056](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2056/_index.html)), swap "Caps lock" to "Num pad" (and create layout for "Caps lock") and use [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/) (for copy/paste/redo/undo and text navigation). I can put it all to public if needed.

For windows you can use [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com).

Comment: Could you post the image you used for the blank layout?

Comment: I'm curious why you're using Keyboard Maestro instead of the one built into the Kinesis keyboard. Also, if you have a link to your setup I would love to see it.

Comment: @jgillman, I don't think it's possible to assign "Redo" and "Undo" to keys natively in the keyboard.

Comment: @Sam I've got 'undo' assigned as a macro for `Command + z` which might be a little hacky since there are some programs that don't use that for undo. For example, vim, it wouldn't smartly switch to `u`. Not sure if that's what you meant by native :)

Comment: @jgillman, oh; I hadn't thought about using the macros for key combos like that. Yeah; that's what I meant by native.

Comment: how did you guys get used to direction keys (up,left,right,bottom) do you have a different layout for them? since you can not replay a macro while holding down a key.. keyboard forces you to remap it..

Answer (score 7):

I ordered my first Kinesis Advantage, I'm very confident I will use it - or a similar keyboard like Ergodox or Axios - for a long time after. I ordered it after a few year of tendinitis-related wrist problems. To relieve these problems I did quite some investigation into different keyboards and keyboard layouts. I tried Colemak until ~50 WPM before finding that it wasn't for me. Though I loved the rhythm of typing with Colemak, the increased lateral movements of my index fingers (due to the location of the D and H keys) were causing physical discomfort. So I went back to QWERTY.

Maybe because of the nature of the Kinesis keyboard (columns rather than orthogonal) I may give Colemak another try, or try another one like Norman or Colemak-DH. Or I just stick with good-old QWERTY, for 30 years hard-wired in my brain...

As I appreciate the thoughts behind any good keyboard layout (any product for that matter), us programmers are often forgotten. It also applies for the  default Kinesis Advantage layout, so I too am looking for a better layout.

In my search for keyboard layouts I came across the Maltron layout (Kinesis Advantage is based on - some rather talk of stolen from - Maltron). Loosely based on the Maltron layout I came up with the layout below for a Mac:

[image]

I tried to move the less keys as possible, so I ended up moving the cursor keys to a different layer, making room for the brackets and <kbd>minus</kbd>/<kbd>plus</kbd> signs. I decided to keep the slashes on their QWERTY-location and only moved the <kbd>backtic</kbd>/<kbd>tilde</kbd> to make room for <kbd>Escape</kbd>.

The function row on the blue layer is based on some Ergodox layout I came across (cannot find the source any more sorry), the cursor keys and <kbd>home</kbd>/<kbd>end</kbd>/<kbd>pgup</kbd>/<kbd>pgdown</kbd> layout is based on several 60% keyboard layouts. Of course the <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>cursor</kbd> keys still work to.

As you see, I stuck with QWERTY for now. Also note, it's not possible to program this layout in the keyboard itself without the use of a foot pedal (the keyboard only support layer togging instead of holding a modifier key).  I use Karabiner to accomplish this (on a Mac).

Please note: I've not put this layout to a test yet, so I'm not sure how easy the brackets, minus and plus are too reach. Or if the <kbd>Command</kbd>-keys are located correctly (for Windows I would put <kbd>CTRL</kbd> here). The <kbd>Hyper</kbd> keys are mapped to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>COMMAND</kbd> in Karabiner, which I use for starting applications quickly. Copy and paste are mappen tol <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> / <kbd>V</kbd>.

References:

- [Maltron vs Dvorak keyboard Layout](http://xahlee.info/kbd/maltron_vs_dvorak_layout.html)
- [Keyboard Layouts Fight! Dvorak, Colemak, Workman, NEO, Bépo](http://xahlee.info/kbd/dvorak_and_all_keyboard_layouts.html)

Comment: How did you configure the "Fn hold" key? On my Kinesis I've manged to remap the Keypad as toggle only.

Comment: @talek I was able to get this working by opening the config file on the flash drive (go to power user mode and then program + F1). I remapped the international backslash key (left hand insert button) with `[intl-\]>[kpshift]` and `[kp-insert]>[kpshift]`. Both key mappings are required to toggle in and out on the one keypress.

Answer (score 2):

I generally program in C++, and use qwerty but swap +/= and Home.  Having to lift my left hand off the keyboard for every assignment or addition would drive me nuts.

Answer (score 2):

My settings file — which can be copy / pasted for Advantage 2. I've settled on this for the last couple of years after a prior few years of iterations.

I use a Dvorak layout on a Mac, though the command-keys are generally applicable to QWERTY.

It's also in a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/farmergreg/kinesis-advantage-2/blob/master/dvorak/mac_dvorak.txt) of these

```
* Cmd keys as easiest to access from thumb
[lctrl]>[lwin]
[rctrl]>[rwin]
[kp-lctrl]>[kp-lwin]
[kp-rctrl]>[kp-rwin]

* Alt keys symmetrical as top inner thumb keys
[rwin]>[ralt]
[kp-rwin]>[kp-ralt]

* Unused key also as Alt. I don't use this much, could put something else here
[intl-\]>[lalt]

* Ctrl keys in tab key position and its symmetric
[tab]>[lctrl]
[/]>[rctrl]

* Tab as easy to access thumb key
[delete]>[tab]
[\]>[hyphen]

* `=` moves to the more traditional position of top right key on keyboard, and hyphen to the traditional dvorak position right of the home row
[=]>[delete]
[hyphen]>[=]
[kp=]>[kp=mac]

* Slashes move to thumb keys together. I don't use home or end so easy to give up
[home]>[/]
[end]>[\]

* Footpedal
[lp-tab]>[rctrl]

* These change pup and pdown into next-tab and prev-tab respectively
{pup}>{speed9}{-rwin}{-lshift}{obrack}{+lshift}{+rwin}
{pdown}>{speed9}{-rwin}{-lshift}{cbrack}{+lshift}{+rwin}

* Escape hatch if you actually need pup or pdown
{lctrl}{pup}>{pup}
{lctrl}{pdown}>{pdown}
```